# Ubuntu no sound, dummy output, and no sound card detected

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

This happened after I installed Skype on my `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`. I found out that Skype had no sound so that I searched for the solution. Someone suggested installing `pavucontrol`

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

After that, it did not solve my Skype problem and it caused my laptop to lose audio output.

I tried a bunch of solutions online, but none of them works. Here are the solutions that I already tried.

```
# solution 1
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload

# then I did
pacmd list-cards

# which gives me
0 card(s) available.

# I also tried
aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

```
#solution 2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo killall pulseaudio
rm -rf ~/.config/pulse
pulseaudio -k
```

I tried these and restarted my laptop. But none of them works. My laptop is `hp spectre x360`. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

**Updates**

I ran the alsa-info script from [here](https://gist.github.com/craftyjon/902247). And this is what I got:

```
upload=true&script=true&cardinfo=
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Wed Mar 18 00:15:45 UTC 2020


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS" HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      HP
Product Name:      HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13-ap0xxx
Product Version:   
Firmware Version:  F.34
Board Vendor:      HP
Board Name:        8514


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0003:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000C:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ELAN2514:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/HPIC0003:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/HPQ6001:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/HPQ8001:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT0E0C:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33A1:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33D3:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33D5:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3400:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3403:01/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3403:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT340E:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT34BB:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:01/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:02/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:03/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:04/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:05/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:07/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0B00:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:00/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:03/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:05/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C09:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP00001:00/status     11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/SYNA327E:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/USBC000:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:11/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:5b/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:5c/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:5f/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.3.0-42-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.3.0-42-generic
Library version:    1.1.3
Utilities version:  1.1.3


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------



!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

--- no soundcards ---


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9dc8] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8514]


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Mar 17 20:11 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Mar 17 20:11 /dev/snd/timer


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...

ARECORD

arecord: device_list:270: no soundcards found...

!!Amixer output
!!-------------


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

ac97_bus
acpi_pad
acpi_thermal_rel
aes_x86_64
aesni_intel
autofs4
binfmt_misc
bluetooth
bnep
btbcm
btintel
btrtl
btusb
ccm
cfg80211
cmac
coretemp
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cros_ec_core
cros_ec_ishtp
cryptd
crypto_simd
drm
drm_kms_helper
ecc
ecdh_generic
fb_sys_fops
ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper
hid
hid_generic
hid_logitech_dj
hid_logitech_hidpp
hid_multitouch
hid_sensor_accel_3d
hid_sensor_custom
hid_sensor_gyro_3d
hid_sensor_hub
hid_sensor_iio_common
hid_sensor_incl_3d
hid_sensor_magn_3d
hid_sensor_rotation
hid_sensor_trigger
hp_wireless
hp_wmi
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i915
idma64
industrialio
industrialio_triggered_buffer
input_leds
int3400_thermal
int3403_thermal
int340x_thermal_zone
intel_cstate
intel_hid
intel_ish_ipc
intel_ishtp
intel_ishtp_hid
intel_ishtp_loader
intel_lpss
intel_lpss_pci
intel_pch_thermal
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_rapl_perf
intel_soc_dts_iosf
intel_wmi_thunderbolt
ip_tables
irqbypass
iwlmvm
iwlwifi
joydev
kfifo_buf
kvm
kvm_intel
ledtrig_audio
libarc4
lp
mac80211
mac_hid
mc
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_me
memstick
nls_iso8859_1
nvme
nvme_core
parport
parport_pc
pinctrl_cannonlake
pinctrl_intel
ppdev
processor_thermal_device
rfcomm
rtsx_pci
rtsx_pci_ms
rtsx_pci_sdmmc
sch_fq_codel
serio_raw
snd
snd_compress
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_ext_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_nhlt
snd_pcm
snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_soc_acpi
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_core
snd_soc_dmic
snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi
snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_skl_ssp_clk
snd_soc_sst_dsp
snd_soc_sst_ipc
snd_sof
snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp
snd_timer
sof_pci_dev
soundcore
sparse_keymap
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
thunderbolt
typec
typec_ucsi
ucsi_acpi
usbhid
uvcvideo
video
videobuf2_common
videobuf2_memops
videobuf2_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc
videodev
virt_dma
wmi
wmi_bmof
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
x_tables


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[    0.143646] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.143647] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.143647] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
--
[    2.551930] thermal thermal_zone6: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[    2.562648] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.564035] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, aborting probe
[    2.585665] audit: type=1400 audit(1584490274.966:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=666 comm="apparmor_parser"
--
[    2.691501] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[    2.692297] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    2.751794] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
--
[    3.043560] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    3.630466] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    3.653190] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: Unsupported HDAudio/iDisp configuration found
[    3.653194] skl_hda_dsp_generic: probe of skl_hda_dsp_generic failed with error -22
```

And here is the output of `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8514
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at 604b118000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 604b000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev
```

Comment: This seems to be related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217862/no-sound-card-found-ubuntu-19-10 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061/

Comment: Thank you, this works for me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I got it worked. Thanks for the help of Jean.

I use the solution here [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1217938/1053942).

Open `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add the following line at the end:

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

Then:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

You will hear the sound.

Comment: This worked for me, but then if I reboot the laptop I get the "Dummy output" sound card problem again. Do you have a permanent solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorted my Toshiba Satellite Radius 12 dummy output

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was updating the kernel with the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. For more information see [this link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-update-kernel-ubuntu).

Comment: Please refrain from posting "link-only answers." if the link you provided goes down in the future, your answer may become obsolete and or useless. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1218918/edit) your question with a brief summary of what to do from the site.

Answer (score -1):

Run into same problem after an update.

You can use the following command to display the audio devices along with the kernel module / driver in use:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
```

I got something like this:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9dc8] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2292]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
```

The second method of this [post](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html) solved my problem: Adding `blacklist snd_soc_skl` to the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

Comment: Welcome to askUbuntu. Consider adding a statement/description of the command you have mentioned.

Comment: @TejasLotlikar I have updated the answer.