# Ubuntu 20.04 "Dummy output" No sound card in use

Tags: 20.04, soundcard

Running latest Ubuntu 20.04 Kernel version 5.4.0-31

Just as simple as other questions about this topic, I've tried every solution available on forums but nothing seems to work, the main problem is that no sound card is in use

With this command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio` there's an output

```
08:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 HD Audio Controller [10de:10f8] (rev a1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU104 HD Audio Controller [1043:8708]
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
08:00.2 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 USB 3.1 Host Controller [10de:1ad8] 
(rev a1)
0a:00.4 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio 
Controller [1022:1487]
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1043:8723]
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
0b:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI 
mode] [1022:7901] (rev 51)
```

but none of them are in use, reloading alsa also shows this so I'm kind of stuck, any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this exact same issue on my issue. I don't know if you are experiencing the same problem because it ended up being that `timidity-daemon` was causing this to appear. I ended up having to remove that and it started working.

The one thing I can suggest as a workaround is running this command

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

This would force my device to start working again.

Answer (score 9):

Found here: [Ubuntu no sound, dummy output, and no sound card detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217949/ubuntu-no-sound-dummy-output-and-no-sound-card-detected?rq=1)

Open `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add the following line at the end:

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

Then:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

You will hear the sound.

Comment: This worked way better than any other fix..   Acer Swift 3 2019

Answer (score 3):

remove timidity:

```
sudo apt-get remove timidity
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This does solve it permanently. Will I miss `timidity` somehow?

Comment: Well, that's something only you know: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TiMidity%2B%2B

Answer (score 1):

This ended up solving by updating Kernel from 5.4 to 5.6, then it was gone instantly if anyone has this issue that sound card is detected but not in use should try that, thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on kernel 5.4.

But if some audio output device is connected during boot, the device seems to function properly, although unplugged devices are not working anymore.

On my environment, a simple solution to avoid using dummy output is leaving at least one audio output device connected during boot. Additionally, this allows others to be plugged in/out.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what devices you are talking about here - the question seems to refer to the internal sound card not working. What specifically is solved by leaving something (what?) plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that timidity-daemon also caused my internal sound card to stop working (20.04, kernel 5.15.0-58). As indicated by nord5 an external USB-soundcard is not affected by this, i.e. it kept working.

Removing timidity-daemon certainly "solves" the problem, in terms of "the card is recognized again" but that is not sufficient imho.

What I'd like to add, is the observation, that the error does not occur, when the timidity daemon is started manually after the system has booted (timidity -iA). In that case the timidity-daemon seems to work (at least it provides a midi device) and the sound cards are working too.

So a better solution might be a script or similar to start the daemon with a delay after the system has started. Unfortunately my linux skills are not sufficient (yet) for this, so I cannot provide a solution but I hope the hint might help others to investigate further in that direction.