# Upgrading to Ubuntu 20 has caused all audio output except HDMI to disappear

Tags: sound, 20.04

I use my 3.5mm output jack from a desktop pc to a receiver for audio. After upgrading to Ubuntu 20, the only audio output that shows up any more is HDMI. I get audio popping and crackling from the HDMI, which is why I use the 3.5 mm jack instead.

Does anyone know why this broke, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Askubuntu!

Have you tried to install pavucontrol?

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

+Check so that nothing is muted (in pavucontrol)

+Related links:

- [Ubuntu 20.04 "Dummy output" No sound card in use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242766/ubuntu-20-04-dummy-output-no-sound-card-in-use)
- [Ubuntu no sound, dummy output, and no sound card detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217949/ubuntu-no-sound-dummy-output-and-no-sound-card-detected?rq=1)

Edit: Glad it worked for you:

From the first link provided:

> Found here: Ubuntu no sound, dummy output, and no sound card detected
>
> Open `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add the following line at
> the end:
>
> ```
> options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```
> pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
> ```
>
> You will hear the sound.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove timidity
> sudo reboot
> ```

Comment: Thank you, the steps in the first link worked.

Comment: Oh @Zaichik Awezome!  editing that in my answer; for the future

Comment: @Zaichik Thank you very much; Hope more people can be helped from this!  //Regards

Comment: I had to do all 3 steps.
Open /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and add the following line at the end:

options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
Then:

pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload

remove timidity:

Comment: @Zaichik Oh - thanks for pointing it out;  what exact steps?  I'm a bit confused; I thought you meant only the 1 accepted answer on the link; ? :)

Comment: I had to modify the alsa-base.conf, did the alsa reboot, and remove timidity software from apt. Just doing the alsa reboot did not work. I also rebooted the OS after doing this.

Comment: @Zaichik Just to confirm; is it correct now?

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you for the help.