# Ubuntu 22.04 Sound Card Exists but is not Detected

Tags: sound

I have been using Ubuntu 22.04 for some time now, but today when I booted up I found that the only output device for sound is Dummy Output and there are no Input Devices. Prior to this, both my microphones and various output devices were being correctly detected in Ubuntu 22.04

Based on inxi -A

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: N/A
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio driver: N/A
  Device-3: Samson C01U Pro condenser microphone type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,usbhid
  Device-4: Sunplus Innovation ezcap U3 capture type: USB driver: N/A
  Device-5: M-Audio Hammer 88 type: USB driver: N/A
  Device-6: Razer USA Kraken Tournament Edition type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,usbhid
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-46-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

I think I've been using the Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS.

aplay -l reports no soundcards found.

So far, I've purge and reinstalled alsa and pulse, rebooted, attempted

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

as per [Upgrade from 21.04 to 22.04, audio lost (Dummy output only)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407616/upgrade-from-21-04-to-22-04-audio-lost-dummy-output-only) , and generally rebooted/shutdown several times along with attempting to reboot pulseaudio control, start it in daemon mode, and so on.

I also attempted to add `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`, as per [Ubuntu no sound, dummy output, and no sound card detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217949/ubuntu-no-sound-dummy-output-and-no-sound-card-detected) , which did not work either. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve the issue. https://askubuntu.com/a/1259818/1161411 suggested that problem might be a missing kernel module, which turned out to be correct.

`find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/sound -name snd-hda-intel.ko`
found nothing, indicating it was missing, and
`sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`
was used to install it.

Comment: your suggestion also saved me on Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem where Pipewire was not recognizing any of the hardware sound cards. The Bluetooth device was still working.

It happened because my user was not included in the `audio` group (`/etc/group`). Adding the user back and re-logging after a restart allowed the user level systemctl Pipewire services to recognize hardware devices.

Basically a permissions issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).