# No soundcards recognised by ALSA, but are installed in the system (22.04)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I'm having quite a difficult time solving an issue with my sound in Ubuntu 22.04. It seems as though no matter what I try, I can't get my system sound-card to be detected. I've tried many things including the excellent help offered by this community to other users [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406646/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working-dummy-audio), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423435/ubuntu-22-04-sound-card-exists-but-is-not-detected) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403575/hdmi-audio-issue-ubuntu-22-04) but nothing seems to be working for me sadly - only Dummy Output appears in the options. I've re-installed ALSA and pulseaudio multiple times, modified the `/etc/default/grub` file in a few different ways and nothing seems to get the job done. I know it's not the devices plugged into the audio jack, as I've tested multiple of them and confirmed they work elsewhere so I'm confident that I'm missing something software related.

I've gone through and processed a diagnostic report through `wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh`, the output of which is [here](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=86806fca68cad9637b642355d04fc33433189cd7).

```
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.5.3
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Tue Mar 26 10:09:00 UTC 2024


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS" PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Trigkey
Product Name:      S5
Product Version:   Default string
Firmware Version:  5800H506
System SKU:        Default string
Board Vendor:      Trigkey
Board Name:        S5


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/AMDI0030:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/CPLM3218:02/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:00/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:01/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:02/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:03/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXVIDEO:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/NXP8013:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A08:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C01:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:01/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:03/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C50:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C50:06/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:32/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:33/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:34/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:35/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:36/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:37/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:38/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:39/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:3a/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:3b/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:3c/status   11


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    #111-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 5 20:16:58 UTC 2024
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     
Library version:    1.2.6.1
Utilities version:  1.2.6


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------



!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

PipeWire:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pipewire)
      Running - Yes

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/home/stephen/anaconda3/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes

Jack:
      Installed - Yes (/home/stephen/anaconda3/bin/jackd)
      Running - No


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------



!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

04:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [1002:1637]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [1002:1637]
04:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    DeviceName: HD Audio Controller


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_hda_intel: model=auto
snd_hda_intel: dmic_detect=0


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------


!!Sysfs card info
!!---------------

!!Card: /sys/class/sound/card*
Driver: 
Tree:
    /sys/class/sound/card*  [error opening dir]


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  1 Mar 26 10:02 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 33 Mar 26 10:02 /dev/snd/timer


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

ARECORD

arecord: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

!!Amixer output
!!-------------


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

aesni_intel
af_alg
algif_hash
algif_skcipher
amdgpu
autofs4
binfmt_misc
bluetooth
bnep
btbcm
btintel
btrtl
btusb
ccp
cec
cfg80211
cm32181
cmac
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
drm
drm_kms_helper
drm_ttm_helper
ecc
ecdh_generic
edac_mce_amd
efi_pstore
fb_sys_fops
ghash_clmulni_intel
gpu_sched
hid
hid_generic
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i2c_hid_acpi
i2c_piix4
industrialio
input_leds
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
iommu_v2
ip_tables
iwlmvm
iwlwifi
joydev
k10temp
kvm
kvm_amd
libarc4
lp
mac80211
mac_hid
msr
nls_iso8859_1
nvme
nvme_core
parport
parport_pc
ppdev
psmouse
r8169
rapl
rc_core
realtek
sch_fq_codel
serio_raw
sha1_ssse3
sha256_ssse3
soundcore
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
ttm
usbhid
video
wmi
wmi_bmof
x_tables
xhci_pci
xhci_pci_renesas


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------



!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-topology-conf                             1.2.5.1-2                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                                  1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.11                     all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                     1.2.6-1ubuntu1                          amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

I'm struggling desperately to get this working, and would be grateful to anyone who can provide any sort of insight to this problem.

**EDIT:** I have re-installed Ubuntu 22.04 freshly from a new iso from the Ubuntu website, and the problem is still persisting. Some further efforts have been attempted:

- Checked everything was unmuted in `alsamixer` (it was).
- When trying to perform `sudo alsa force-reload`, it hangs on the Unloading phase at `snd-rn-pci-acp3x` and cannot complete.
- Running `lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel` shows that I am running `snd_hda_intel`, though I'm not too sure how to progress.